# Altova Mapforce: Multiply single sequence values with single sequence values

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, map-force

im looking for a solution to my problem. I am using altova mapforce 2015 x64 with xslt2.

I have two sequences of numbers in xslt2. they both have the same length (and always will). e.g. they look like this:

seq1: 10 20 ...

seq2: 1 2 ...

What i need is to multiply those two in the way that seq1[0] is multiplied with seq2[0], seq[1]*seq[1] and so on.

so in my needed solution i would get the sequence 10 40 instead i get the following 10 20 20 40. so the whole sequences are multiplied.

so maybe somebody knows an answer or a workaround to that problem, both is highly appreciated.

thanks

**EDIT:**

the problem with altova is that i cannot add xslt2 code myself, the file will be overwritten everytime i modify something in the mapping.

Comment: Is this question related to XSLT? If so, can you please show an XML input and the XSLT code you have so far?

Comment: Yes it is realted to XSLT2. im using altova mapforce, so I am not writing the code by hand it is generated. the XSLT2 file has almost 38k of lines, so theres not really a possibility to post the code. I cannot even find the part im describing.

Comment: So, how do we know what kind of answer is useful to you if not code?

Comment: a function in altova mapforce would be great. maybe somebody ran into that issue before me.

the problem with altova is that i cannot add xslt2 code myself, the file will be overwritten everytime i modify something in the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `xsl:for-each` and a range to determine the position. Here's an example...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="seq1" select="(10,20)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="seq2" select="(1,2)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="newSeq" as="item()*">
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to max((count($seq1),count($seq2)))">
                <xsl:sequence select="$seq1[current()] * $seq2[current()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>                        
        </xsl:variable>
        <results>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newSeq" separator=","/>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (separated by commas just to show it's a sequence)

```
<results>10,40</results>
```

Note: This will only handle an even number of sequence items. If either sequence has more than the other, those will not be included in the output. You'd have to add additional logic if you needed to handle that situation.

**EDIT** - Just saw your comment about not being able to add XSLT code yourself. I'll leave my answer here in case someone not using mapforce finds this answer useful.

Comment: i will try to rebuild that within mapforce. thank you anyway.